# can i pass query in request parameter in wso2 DSS

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I have written a query in DSS like:

```
select ID,Name,Age,Address from person where ID in (?)
```

Now when i am accessing the above created service in Soap UI utility, there i am passing request as :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:person="http://tempuri.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <person:GetPersonData>
         <person:ID>select distinct ID from person</person:ID>
      </person:GetPersonData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now in the request i am passing query, But the above request doesn't give me any response,But when i execute the above query i.e.

```
select ID,Name,Age,Address from person where ID in (select distinct ID from person)
```

in query browser of MYSQL i get response. 
So my question is how can i pass query in input parameter of service.
Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the sample at [1}. It demonstrates your exact scenario.

[1].http://wso2.com/project/data-services/2.6.2/docs/samples/rdbms_sample.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.